# How to wait for a thread in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I create a new Thread,

```
$script = {
 write-host "in script.."
}

$p = [PowerShell]::Create()
$null= $p.AddScript($script).AddArgument($object)
$p.BeginInvoke()
```

The problem is the application execute is exit **before** the $script is finished. I know that I can use `sleep until` But I want to run this code within the ForEach, So After the ForEach is complete It wait until the threads are complete.

(I Need to use Create because I pass an object)

Who Can I tell powershell to stay until all the script is execute?

Comment: [I'd recommend reading this series of articles](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/28/beginning-use-of-powershell-runspaces-part-3/) as it basically explains what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also have a look at Background Jobs https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/04/18/background-jobs-in-powershell.aspx

Runspaces are very powerful but not that well documented. If you are trying to do some simple stuff, maybe the jobs is an easier approach.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is using `Write-Host`.  You can't do anything with that output and it's not reliable to show up between hosts.  You also didn't capture the job state after `BeginInvoke`.  This following example will work:

```
$p = [powershell]::Create()
$null = $p.AddScript('"Testing!"')
$r = $p.BeginInvoke()

while (-not $r.IsCompleted) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
}

$runspaceResult = $p.EndInvoke($r)
```

Comment: That's good, But I need to run this code within the foreach. so I just update my question.